# SQL - IN dentro de um SUB SELECT com NOT IN - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Queria tornar meu INSERT dinâmico, que não precise de eu alterar os ids manualmente.

Tenho esse script que me retorna todos PRODUTOS que não possui 83 relacionamento com a tabela EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA

```
SELECT prod.ID_PRODUTO AS "ID DO PRODUTO" FROM ERP.EST_PRODUTO prod
LEFT JOIN ERP.EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA prodEmp ON prodEmp.ID_PRODUTO = 
prod.ID_PRODUTO
GROUP BY  prod.ID_PRODUTO
HAVING COUNT(prodEmp.ID_PRODUTO) !=83
```

Meu retorno e de 22 dados (ID_PRODUTO), feito isso preciso de outro script para retornar as empresas que não estão relacionada com esses ID_PRODUTO na tabela EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA . para eu criar um insert e fazer esse relacionamento.

```
SELECT DISTINCT emp.ID_EMPRESA FROM ERP.CF_EMPRESA emp
WHERE EMP.ID_EMPRESA NOT IN (select emp.id_empresa FROM
ERP.EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA prd
LEFT JOIN ERP.EST_PRODUTO prod ON prod.ID_PRODUTO = prd.ID_PRODUTO
INNER JOIN ERP.CF_EMPRESA emp ON prd.ID_EMPRESA = emp.ID_EMPRESA
WHERE prod.ID_PRODUTO = 127011575) /*id que consegui no script a cima*/
```

Com esse retorno do ID_EMPRESA eu crio meu INSERT .
O id eu uso sequence com um trigger

```
INSERT INTO EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA ( ID_PRODUTO, ID_EMPRESA,  
    CUSTO_OPERACIONAL, OUTRAS_DESPESAS)
VALUES (127011575, 793, 0, 0)
```

Mas quando eu tento juntar os sql não tenho resultado preciso pois tem produto que não tem relacionamento com empresa X, mas o outro produto não tem relacionamento com empresa Y mas tem com empresa X que o outro produto não possuía.

```
SELECT DISTINCT emp.ID_EMPRESA FROM ERP.CF_EMPRESA emp
WHERE EMP.ID_EMPRESA NOT IN 
    (SELECT emp.id_empresa FROM
    ERP.EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA prd
    LEFT JOIN ERP.EST_PRODUTO prod ON prod.ID_PRODUTO = prd.ID_PRODUTO
    INNER JOIN ERP.CF_EMPRESA emp ON prd.ID_EMPRESA = emp.ID_EMPRESA
    WHERE prod.ID_PRODUTO  IN(
     SELECT prod.ID_PRODUTO AS "ID DO PRODUTO" FROM ERP.EST_PRODUTO prod
     LEFT JOIN ERP.EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA prodEmp ON
         prodEmp.ID_PRODUTO = prod.ID_PRODUTO
     GROUP BY  prod.ID_PRODUTO
     HAVING COUNT(prodEmp.ID_PRODUTO) !=83 ))
```

Não sei como tratar cada ID_PRODUTO separadamente da lista até o termino dela, meu NOT IN  não sabe diferencia cada sub SELECT. 
Alguem sabe uma solução ate mesmo com PL/SQL?

Comment: não seria ...  WHERE (prod.ID_PRODUTO ,prod.ID_EMPRESA) IN (
     SELECT prod.ID_PRODUTO , prod.ID_EMPRESA ? Chave dupla ...

Comment: vou tentar, não sabia dessa possibilidade de chave dupla.

Comment: Cheguei ao mesmo resultado que se tivesse usado EXISTS, ele me trouxe uma empresa que não vinculo nenhuma com a tabela EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA , e como meu caso precisaria que trazer as empresas que estavam vinculado ao produto mas n possuía vinculo na tabela EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA pois essa tabela contem o ID de Produto e Empresa. Apelei para o PL/SQL e acho que vai me da o resultado que preciso.

Comment: Precisa conhecer a estrutura das tabelas e os relacionamentos para que alguém possa opinar.

Comment: O relacionamento e bem simples, tenho EST_PRODUTO, CF_EMPRESA cada uma com suas devidas variáveis, ai tenho EST_PRODUTO_EMPRESA, QUE possui ID de cada uma, e tenho EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA que também possui o ID de cada uma, e uns double adicionais.

Comment: Creio que vc precise fazr o rel. emp e produto para cada join , pelo que entendi o produto x difere da empres 1 para a empresa 2, correto :?

Comment: correto, tipo com PL/SQL já entendi como fazer, mas usando SQL não não vi uma solução

Comment: Por acaso esse poste com sua resposta, de 2010 me ajudou no PL/SQL tbm kkk [https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/411769-resolvido-resultado-de-select-dentro-de-uma-variável/]

Comment: Este post merecia uma arrumada , uma conclusão.

Comment: @Motta blz? Na época que resolvi meu problema com PL/SQL pois precisava fazer insert com dados de outras duas tabelas.

Answer (score 0):

[CONCLUSÃO] Utilizando PL/SQL

random_uuid() e uma function minha que gerar valores UUID.

```
DECLARE 

FOR V_FUNC IN
    (SELECT  prod.ID_PRODUTO FROM ERP.EST_PRODUTO prod
                INNER JOIN ERP.EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA prodEmp on prodEmp.ID_PRODUTO = prod.ID_PRODUTO
                GROUP BY  prod.ID_PRODUTO
                HAVING COUNT(prodEmp.ID_PRODUTO) !=83) 
LOOP

            FOR V_FUNC_EMPRESA IN (SELECT DISTINCT emp.ID_EMPRESA FROM ERP.CF_EMPRESA emp
                                            WHERE EMP.ID_EMPRESA NOT IN (select emp.id_empresa FROM ERP.EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA prd
                                            INNER JOIN ERP.EST_PRODUTO prod ON prod.ID_PRODUTO = prd.ID_PRODUTO
                                            INNER JOIN ERP.CF_EMPRESA emp ON prd.ID_EMPRESA = emp.ID_EMPRESA
                                            WHERE prod.ID_PRODUTO = V_FUNC.ID_PRODUTO)
                                            AND EMP.ID_EMPRESA != 110)

                    LOOP
                         INSERT

                                        INSERT 
                                                    INTO EST_PROD_PRECO_CUSTO_EMPRESA 
                                                            (
                                                                                                    ID_PRODUTO, 
                                                             ID_EMPRESA, CUSTO_OPERACIONAL,
                                                                                         OUTRAS_DESPESAS, 
                                                                    PERCENTUAL_OUTRAS_DESPESAS, 
                                                                                                 PRECO_CUSTO, 
                                                                                     PRECO_CUSTO_FINAL, 
                                                                                     PRECO_CUSTO_MEDIO, 
                                                                                    OTAL_OUTROS_CUSTOS,
                                                                OUTROS_CUSTOS_ULTIMA_ENTRADA,
                                                                                                                UUID, 
                                                                                DATA_ULTIMO_REAJUSTE
                                                            )
                                            VALUES
                                                (
                                                                V_FUNC.ID_PRODUTO, 
                                                                V_FUNC_EMPRESA.ID_EMPRESA, 
                                                                        0,
                                                                        0, 
                                                                        0,
                                                                        0, 
                                                                        0,
                                                                        0,
                                                                        0, 
                                                                        0, 
                                                random_uuid(),
                                                            SYSDATE
                                                )

                                ;

            END LOOP;

END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: isso é a resposta ou algo que complemente a dúvida? se a resposta for a segunda opção, é melhor você editar a pergunta do que adicionar o texto como uma resposta ;)

Comment: é uma previa em PL/SQL mas queria saber se era possível fazer usando apenas SQL.